# How to add data to request object in hapi?

Tags: node.js, typescript, request, hapi.js

I want to add data to the request object for each request. Hence I subscribed to the `onRequest` event and am doing:

```
server.ext('onRequest', (request, reply) => {
    console.log('I AM CALLED');
    const marketCode : Market = request.params["market-code"];
    const operatorCode : Operator = request.params["operator-code"];

    request.operatorContext = new OperatorContext(
        operatorEndpointEnv,
        operatorCode,
        marketCode
    );

    console.log(request.operatorContext); // will be defined


    return reply.continue();
});
```

Yet when my controller:

```
function apiStatus(req, reply) {
    console.log(req.operatorContext); // will be undefined

    reply.status(204).end();
}
```

recieves the call, the request is just plain has `request.operatorContext` as undefined, yet it set within the context of the adding the extension it is defined, as I can see it logged:

```
I AM CALLED
OperatorContext { environment: 'test', operator: undefined, market: undefined }
undefined
```

How to load my custom data to a request object?

Comment: Look at `request.app` in the docs.

Comment: sorry to point the obvious, but in the code above, in the controller function, I see reply.operatorContext() instead of request.operatorContext() ...  I did a quick & dirty test on one of my controllers and it seems to be ok.  Could it be a copy/paste issue when posting ?